# Implementing Factory Method design pattern in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, factory

i have the following code:

**Product code -**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Guns : MonoBehaviour //product
{
    public abstract void shoot();
    public GameObject CreateBullet(GameObject bullet)
    {
        return Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    public void ShootBullet(GameObject bullet, Vector3 direction)
    {
        bullet.transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

**Concrete Product Code 1**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class M16 : Guns //ConcreteProduct
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject m16bullet;
    Vector3 m16bulletdirection = new Vector3(5, 0, 0);

    public override void shoot()
    {
        CreateBullet(m16bullet);
        ShootBullet(m16bullet, m16bulletdirection);
    }

}
```

**Concrete Product Code 2**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Uzi : Guns //ConcreteProduct
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject uzibullet;
    Vector3 uzibulletdirection = new Vector3(10, 0, 0);

    public override void shoot()
    {
        CreateBullet(uzibullet);
        ShootBullet(uzibullet, uzibulletdirection);
    }
}
```

**Creator Code**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class GunCreator : MonoBehaviour //Creator
{
    public abstract Guns GunFactory();
}
```

**Concrete Creator Code 1**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class M16Creator : GunCreator // ConcreteCreator
{

    public override Guns GunFactory()
    {
        return new M16();
    }
}
```

**Concrete Creator Code 2**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UziCreator : GunCreator // ConcreteCreator
{
    public override Guns GunFactory()
    {
        return new Uzi();
    }
}
```

and a client code, which currently do nothing as I dont know how to make a gun using this method. So How do all of this help me create new gun prefab with the relevant code on them?

Besides, as far as i understand, every new gun will have to have a NewGunCreator class that derives from GunCreator and a NewGun class that derives from Guns. wouldnt it be easier to leave out the creator classes?

cheers!

Comment: Does this make any sense? You basically just implemented methods containing one line ... a built-in for every class reachable API call ... why not simply directly make the API call then?

Comment: Also since you are dealing here with `MonoBehaviour` it is not allowed to do `new M16()` .. the only allowed ways for creating instances of `MonoBehaviour` is via `AddComponent`, `Instantiate` or the constructor of `GameObject`

Comment: What is `new Uzi();` meant to actually do? Is it meant to create a new gameobject with an `Uzi` script attached to it?  Is it meant to add an instance of `Uzi` script to the same object `GunCreator` is attached to? Desired outcome is unclear. As `derHugo` says, `MonoBehiour`s should not be instantiated with `new`.

Comment: @derHugo thanks for the clarifcation :)
@Ruzihm ```new Uzi();``` should create a new gameobject with an ```Uzi``` script attached to it

Comment: The `GunCreator`s would need a field like `public M16 prefab;` and then you would go `return Instantiate prefab;` ... still though: This doesn't make any sense in my eyes ... you could as well instead directly make this API call without having a factory for that ... The factory pattern is mainly ment to initialize some internal and private fields and configurations that shall remain hidden and unchangeable for the outside classes  and obfuscate where exactly that new instance comes from and of what exact type it is ... Doesn't really se to be the case here

Comment: @derHugo I read that the factory pattern is needed where objects are to be created out of a "factory" - so if i wanted a new gun i could just add ```NewGun``` (and maybe ```CreateNewGun```?) and extend the method without braking the code...

Comment: @OmriAzran sure .. it's a pattern ;) there are many ways to implement it and of course if there is going to be more about it it makes sense ... what I'm saying is as long as there is only one thing happening in that method .. you don't really need a method for it. So question is why not do `public Guns GunFactory(Guns prefab){ return Instantiate(prefab); };` ... that is basically the same way you did it with the bullets

Comment: Btw further: `CreateBullet(uzibullet); ShootBullet(uzibullet, uzibulletdirection);` makes no sense .. what you want is rather `var bullet = CreateBullet(uzibullet); ShootBullet(bullet, uzibulletdirection);` .. but this still makes no sense since your `ShootBullet` needs to be called **every frame** otherwise you move only exactly one step away from the spawn point ;)

Comment: @derHugo first of all, thanks for all the help!
Second thing is -  Im doing this project to demonstrate my knowledge and get a job but clearly i dont have enough of it... how would you go from here in order to master the design of unity games?